# Assign a value from a subscribe method to an attribute

Tags: angular

So first of all I'd like you to check this :

```
load(){
   return this._http.get(url)
        .map(res => {
            return res.json();
        })
        .map(data=>{
            //some code
            return {notifs,cpt};
         });
}

export class HomePage {

notificationsList: Array<Notification> = [];
nonLu: number;

constructor(
    private _userService: UserService,
    private _router: Router,
    public _notificationService: NotificationsService) {
    _notificationService.load()
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.nonLu = res.cpt;
            res.notifs.forEach((resObject) => {
                this.notificationsList.unshift(resObject);
            });
        });


}
```

}

As you can see in the file notifications.service.ts, I have the load method which loads the notifications of a specific user (to be more accurate, that method returns the notifications and the number of unread notifications as well).

Since the load method returns an Observable, I have to use the subscribe method in home.component.ts. In the subscribe method, i'd like to assign to the attribute "nonLu" a certain value (in this case res.cpt). But I have a problem when I type console.log(nonLu) inside the subscribe method, I have the expected value. Otherwise, I get undefined.

What can I do to solve this issue ?

Thank you

**Update**

```
constructor( private _userService: UserService, private _router: Router, public _notificationService: NotificationsService) {
    _notificationService.load() 
    .subscribe(res => { 
        res.notifs.forEach((resObject) => {    
            this.notificationsList.unshift(resObject); 
        }); 
        this.nonLu = res.cpt; 
        console.log("Inside subscribe : " + this.nonLu); 
     }); 
     console.log("Outside subscribe : " + this.nonLu); 
}
```

Comment: plunker isn't working correctly as you're accessing files that you have locally.

Comment: You should type: `console.log(this.nonLu);`...

Comment: If console log in `.subscribe(res => {
                console.log(res.cpt);
                this.nonLu = res.cpt;})` prints the expected value, then `this.nonLu` also will get the expected value assigned. The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: How did you check whether `this.nonLu` got the value assigned?

Comment: My bad the error isn't about forgetting "this" before the variable (I just forgot to type it here). Inside the subscribe this.nonLu gets the expected value (obviously). Outside of subscribe, I get undefined

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer right after the line this.nonLu = res.cpt, I tried console.log(this.nonLu) and I got the value 2 (the expected value) but once I'm outside of subscribe, I get "undefined"

Comment: Could provide the content of the template where you try to display the hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Observables are async, this means that the callback passed to `subscribe(...)` will executed eventually but not immediately. JavaScript (or TypeScript) continue to execute with the next code line.
`subscribe()` is only to register interest to get ones own code called once a value is emitted.

```
constructor(
    private _userService: UserService,
    private _router: Router,
    public _notificationService: NotificationsService) {
    _notificationService.load()
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.nonLu = res.cpt;
            res.notifs.forEach((resObject) => {
                this.notificationsList.unshift(resObject);
        });
        /// code here is executed before the callback passed to subscribe
    });
}
```

Comment: Indeed when I type console.log() where you put ///, this console.log is executed after the one I put right before the end of the constructor.
But isn't there a way to reverse the order of execution ?

Comment: So inside the value is printed, and outside it isn't, right? (I added the code to your question - longer code in comments is unreadable)

Comment: That's expected behavior like explained above. The 2nd `console.log()` is printed before the function passed to `subscribe(...)` is executed.

Comment: This is just how async execution works. As "workaround" you can just move the code inside `subscribe(...)` or add `.subscribe(...).toPromise.then(console.log(this.nonLu));`

Comment: Well Atom tells me toPromise isn't available for a Subscription object and as for putting the code inside of subscribe, since in my mobile application, I'd like to display the number of unread notifications (which is what the variable nonLu is here for), it won't change a thing. But thank you for your time anyway :)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You'd need `.map(...)` instead of `subscribe(...)` then you can add `toPromise(...)`. I don't see how moving the code inside or outside of `subscribe()` changes anything. When do you want the code that you planned to add outside of `subscribe()` to be called?

Comment: Actually what I want is that when the class HomePage is instantiated, the variable nonLu has the right value right away.
I'm working on a mobile application developed with Nativescript and Angular 2 : basically, when I launch the app, I have the login page. Once I'm logged in, I have the homepage which has 2 tabs : the actual homepage and the notifications tabs. The title of the notifications tab has the number of unread notifications. And for the moment, undefined is always displayed

Comment: I don't see why this would be necessary. If you still need the value "right away" you can't use `Observable`. You could provide it to `bootstrap(AppComponent, [provide('nonLu', {useValue: nonLuValue})])`, then you can inject it to the constructor `constructor(@Inject('nonLu') private nonLu) { }`.

Comment: Actually when `subscribe()` is called because the value arrived, then `undefined` shouldn't be displayed anymore (`undefined` should be replaced by the recieved value in a matter of milliseconds). Maybe there is another issue that leads to `undefined` still being displayed. You question doesn't provide enough information to tell.

Comment: But in the beginning nonLu has no value. That's what the load method is here for : I get the notifications and the number of unread notifications as well. Then I assign this value to nonLu.

Maybe I'm doing it wrong

Edit : Ok I'll check if the problem comes from somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

As Gunter has said is true. But as a workaround you can use `setInterval`. Though this is not the best solution, but can be considered as a workaround.

```
constructor( private _userService: UserService, private _router: Router, public _notificationService: NotificationsService) {
    _notificationService.load() 
    .subscribe(res => { 
        res.notifs.forEach((resObject) => {    
            this.notificationsList.unshift(resObject); 
        }); 
        this.nonLu = res.cpt; 
        console.log("Inside subscribe : " + this.nonLu); 
     }); 

     let i=setInterval(()=>{
         if(this.nonLu)
         {
             console.log(this.nonLu);
             clearInterval(i);
         }
     },1000)

}
```

Comment: I'd consider this an anti-pattern. What if it takes more then 5 seconds for the first value to arrive, why wait 5 secs if the value arrives 5ms later? You can just move the code inside `subscribe(...)` or add `subscribe(...).toPromise.then(console.log(this.nonLu))`

Comment: well the setInterval isn't really what I want anyway ^^ because even though I have the right value in the console, on my mobile application, I still get undefined

Comment: Yes I said this is not the best solution as `this.nonLu` is dependent on server. That's why I didn't write `setInterval(....,1000)`, i wrote `setInterval(....,5000)`. I could have written `setInterval(....,10000)`. But let PO decide that time. I just provided a workaround nothing else.

Comment: now check my workaround. Now I don't think there will be any trouble.